# bytes value of 8 bytes or 16 bytes number

Tags: c++, gcc, memory, clang, c++17

I assume every byte should be valued 0 if a long var is initialized to 0. (same for __int128)

This is a piece of testing code:

```
    int64_t i64 = { 0 };
    auto addr = &i64;
    LOG(INFO) << "i64 address=" << addr << ": " << i64;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(i64); i++) {
      LOG(INFO) << addr + i << ": byte=" << (int)*reinterpret_cast<int8_t*>(addr + i);
    }
```

I expect to see all 0 for each byte. However, it is not the case, here is result by running on *"Mac Mojave 10.14.6" with clang*

> Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.12) Target:
>   x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0 Thread model: posix InstalledDir:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

I1113 23:26:05.741184 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:498] i64 address=0x7ffeeb589a90: 0 
I1113 23:26:05.741191 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:500] 0x7ffeeb589a90: byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.741196 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:500] 0x7ffeeb589a98: byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.741201 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:500] 0x7ffeeb589aa0: byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.741205 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:500] 0x7ffeeb589aa8: byte=1 
I1113 23:26:05.741210 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:500] 0x7ffeeb589ab0: byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.741214 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:500] 0x7ffeeb589ab8: byte=-126 
I1113 23:26:05.741219 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:500] 0x7ffeeb589ac0: byte=96 
I1113 23:26:05.741223 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:500] 0x7ffeeb589ac8: byte=1

**What might be reasons for this? Is it related to memory order or CPU cache sync? Or these are legal bytes value for a 0 long?**

---

However, if I use a union to wrap it, I could see all bytes are valued in zero:

```
  union U {
    int128_t a;
    int8_t b[16];
  };

  U u = { 0 };
  LOG(INFO) << "value=" << *reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(u.b + 8);
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    LOG(INFO) << "byte=" << (int)u.b[i];
  }
```

output:
I1113 23:26:05.757899 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:539] value=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757905 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757910 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757915 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757920 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757925 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757928 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757932 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757936 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757942 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757946 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757951 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757956 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757959 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757966 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757970 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0 
I1113 23:26:05.757975 103323072 TestCommon.cpp:541] byte=0

**Appreciate any insights and input...**

Comment: `addr + i` is moving forward `i * sizeof(i64)`, not 1. You can see that the address being printed is being incremented by 8. It seems you expect it to be incremented by 1.

Comment: not sure about the first snippet, but the second has undefined behaviour. It is not allowed to use unions for type punning. It comes up as a suggestion quite frequently, but the standard says otherwise

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior land.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
auto addr = &i64;
```

creates:

```
int64_t* addr = &i64;
```

so every time you increment `addr` it goes up by `sizeof int64_t`.

You want something more like:

```
uint8_t* addr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&i64);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I missed the basics!